# Apache error log shows PHP errors but no errors outputted by PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have just had a look at the apache error log and the file is huge! There have been no errors on the site itself and none are outputted by PHP but in the error log there are many undefined variables etc.

Here's a couple of examples:

```
[Fri May 31 14:04:15 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ID in C:\\wamp\\www\\artist_profile.php on line 189, referer: http://localhost/Discover

[Fri May 31 14:04:15 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/Discover

[Fri May 31 14:04:15 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\artist_profile.php:0, referer: http://localhost/Discover
```

I have no idea why this is happening and obviously need to sort it before the site goes live.

I can't really give any more information on this because I am clueless. I have playing around with `include` and `include_once`, swapping them around but this had no effect. My only other thought is that the site use a history API script to fetch pages through ajax without a full refresh. Maybe because only part of the new page is loaded in errors are being logged. But I don't see why they would be logged in apache and not outputted into the browser.

**Edit**

The variable `$ID` that the notice is identifying is gotten from a mysql query and identified as such;

```
$ID = $row['ID'];//never echo this
```

Line 189 is just `$ID` inside another query. I can echo out $ID anywhere on the page and no error will be displayed. By the way the comment is there to remind anyone not to echo it out for security reasons.

Edit
Where `$ID` is set.

```
<?php require("includes/database.php"); 
       $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; //get url for db
       $url = substr($url, 1);
       $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * ,
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist_follows WHERE follows_ID = A.ID) AS followers,
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist_follows WHERE ID = A.ID) AS following,
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracks WHERE ID = A.ID) AS tracks
                              FROM artists A WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1");
       $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
       if ($count === 0){
       //redirect to 404
       header ("location:404");
       }
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $ID = $row['ID'];//never echo this           
      }
```

Line 189:

```
WHERE E.ID = '$ID'
GROUP BY E.E_ID
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Comment: Show us artist_profile.php line 189?

Comment: Those aren't errors. That's a notice and it's followup messages.

Comment: @Patrick Okay so why are they occuring? The variable is defined

Comment: It says it's not defined. We can't know until you show us the code.

Comment: @nbs189 going to need to see more context of the script. `$ID` may be out of scope where you use it. Also, please show line 189. Just change anything sensitive to something ambiguous.

Comment: What happens is that you have `log_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I wouldn't recommend he turn that off. It's obvious that he has an actual issue here or it wouldn't be logging anything.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I do want to log my errors so I can remove them

Comment: I didn't say that it was bad, but merely that the reason these errors are appearing in the apache log was because of that setting.

Comment: @crush I also don't understand why, if the variable is out of scope, it would only show as a notice on the log. Nothing is effected, the script works as it should

Comment: @nbs189 Your query would still execute if `$ID` is out of scope there, though it probably wouldn't return any rows. I can't really tell from what you've given, though. What version of PHP are you using? In earlier versions of PHP, `$ID` would go out of scope at the end of that while loop since it is not declared outside of the loop first.

Comment: @crush I am struggling to give you anymore information as have given you all that is relevant. I cant execute `$ID` outside the loop absolutely fine, that was the first thing i checked. The only thing I can think of is that when a page is loaded via the history API script the $ID is not loaded in. But if that were the case then you would have thought none of the script that used `$ID` would work but that does not happen.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas with what you've given. Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: @crush fair enough, thanks for trying. I will keep trying to figure it out. It causes no problems with the webpage itself so is not a huge issue

Answer (score 1):

This is because they are just notices. Those are probably disabled in your `php.ini`. You can either activate by editing it or simply add in your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

You might want to have a look at [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: @nbs189 is the error still in log rightnow? or are them from previous hours?

Comment: The notice is in the log yes. I have deleted the log several times and is still there when revisitng page. If i put `echo ini_get('display_errors');` a `1` is displayed. I guess this means there is 1 error

Comment: @nbs189 did you add what i wrote at the top of `artist_profile.php`?

Comment: Yes I added it to the top of that and to the top of a template that is included on every page

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this at the beginning of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```